# How many threads are there here?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public Demo implements Runnable(){
   private String threadName;
   public Thread t;

   public Demo(String name){
     this.threadName = name;
   }

   public void begin(){
      t = new Thread(this,threadName);
      t.start();
   }

   public void run(){
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       System.out.println("Running");
   }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
   Demo demo1 = new Demo("DEMO1");
   demo1.begin();
   Demo demo2 = new Demo("DEMO2");
   demo2.begin();
}
```

Okay, I am a little confused about Thread even after reading API and documentations. My understanding is that, if you either implement Runnable() or extend Thread class, it creates its own thread.

So in this case, 
The Public static void main() creates the "Main Thread", then its children are the 2 subsequent threads (Demo objects), and after calling "begin()", there are another 2 threads stemming from Demo objects.

1. There are 5 threads in this code?
2. Thread.sleep(1000) seem to stop all of the threads, thus it is referring to the "Main Thread"?
3. If I call synchronized(this) in run() method inside Demo class, Demo1 has owns its monitor at the same time Demo2 owns its monitor, doing its own task simultaneously? Or because they share one common "Main Monitor", they go execute one at a time, waiting in queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `start()` on a `Thread` object starts a new thread. A plain `Runnable` does not create new threads, only `Thread` objects do.

> There are 5 threads in this code?

There are three threads.

> Thread.sleep(1000) seems to stop all of the threads.

It's called from the two new threads and delays them for one second.

The reason the entire program appears to stop is that a program doesn't terminate if there are other active threads (unless those threads are [daemon threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon-boolean-), which these aren't). The main thread will have already exited, but the existence of your two extra threads will cause the program to continue running until those threads have finished.

> If I call `synchronized(this)` in `run()` method inside Demo class, Demo1 has owns its monitor at the same time Demo2 owns its monitor, doing its own task simultaneously?

Threads will only block if they synchronize on the same object. `this` refers to two different objects, so the threads will not block each other.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that, if you either implement Runnable() or extend Thread class, it creates its own thread.

Thread will be created only when you create the Thread explicitly. Your `begin()` method in `Demo` create thread during execution of this statement

```
t = new Thread(this,threadName);
```

> There are 5 threads in this code?

Three application threads (Main, DEMO1 and DEMO2 ) are created apart from four system threads (`Reference Handler,Signal Dispatcher,Attach Listener,Finalizer`).

> Thread.sleep(1000) seems to stop all of the threads.

No. It stops the thread for which this statement has been invoked. In your case, it may be either DEMO1 or DEMO2.

> If I call synchronized(this) in run() method inside Demo class, Demo1 has owns its monitor at the same time Demo2 owns its monitor, doing its own task simultaneously? Or because they share one common "Main Monitor", they go execute one at a time, waiting in queue.

If you call synchronized(this) in run() method inside Demo class, monitor has been acquired on the object for which you run() method is executing. In this case, it's either DEMO1 or DEMO2. These two objects are not sharing the monitor lock unless you change this with className => `synchronized(Demo.Class)`

Refer to this this documentation [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for more details.

> making these methods synchronized has two effects:
>
> 1. First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
> 2. Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.